# Spring MVC returning 500 error? How can I debug it?

Tags: spring-mvc, java-ee-7

I have a project using spring MVC.

- The request is recieved correctly.
- The dispatcher servlet correctly maps the request to the controller.
- The controller correctly processes the request and generates the proper response
- The model-map is populated and the correct view is returned
- At this point spring magic kicks in and I lose track of the specifics of what's going on.

On the client-side, the response (via firebug) is a 500 error and nothing else. Without firebug my client just hangs.

I have no idea how I can debug the dispatcher servlet, and figure out what the problem is. I can't step through the spring binaries with a debugger, and it's not throwing any sort of exception so I can't look at a stack trace. All I have to look at are configuration files which, i'm almost 100% certain are fine.

What steps can I take to debug this problem? What tools or approaches can I use?

Details: 
I'm using Eclipse IDE, Java EE 7 and an ant script to build the project. I'm deploying to tomcat 7.

Comment: Are you using an IDE? Which one? Are you using Maven? Download the source jars and then you will be able to step through it.

Comment: Is downloading the source-jars the next reasonable step in debugging this problem, or are you just adding that comment because I mentioned stepping through the code?

Comment: No, just for stepping through the code. You should also set your logger to debug and check what gets logged. Spring has very good log statements.

Comment: I've been checking the tomcat logs and I'm getting nothing about spring at all... is there another log i should be checking??

Comment: What's the output of catalina.out?  You should be seeing a stacktrace in it.